# Does Connect-MsolService -Credential no longer work?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm attempting to create the ability to connect to my o365 instance through the use of connect-msolservice. Im running into the issue that no matter what I try Im unable to use -Credential to feed it a username and password and avoid a prompt. This is a massive issue as there is literally no point in attempting to automate a process unless it automates the connection too.

Currently what I'm trying to use:

```
$AdminName = "admin email account"
$Pass = Get-Content "C:\test.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $Pass

Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

Everywhere I check online tells me that this should be possible and for the life of me I cant find anything obvious that I'm doing incorrectly, albeit, all the posts and info I do find are about a year old. This leads me to the question, is this simply no longer supported? If not and hopefully this is the case, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How do you define "does not work"? Do you receieve error messages? I just tried using Connect-MSOLService with the -Credentials paramter (using some credentials I've set with Get-Credential) and for me it works. Keep in mind that if your account has MFA enabled that you can't use this parameter

Comment: @bluuf I define not working because of the forced prompted after attempting to feed creds. The account does not make use of MFA, I simply wish to establish a connection without any user input once the script runs. Currently, that doesn't seem possible, whenever attempting to run this is met with the GUI with manual input prompts.